# Swift uitableview load more from API

Tags: ios, swift

I get 20 characters from APi "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/"
in tableview, but here 493 characters and one page only displays 20. How do I display 493 characters in tableview?
can someone help me plz?
I am looking for information on google, but can not find the answer to my question

Here code:

```
class UsersTableViewController: UITableViewController {



    var characters = [Results]()



     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

        LoadCharacters()

    }
    func LoadCharacters() {
        let urlString = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/"


        if let url = URL(string: urlString)
        {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, responce, error) in
            if error != nil {
                       print(error!)
                       return
            }

                if let safeData = data {
                    self.parseJson(usersData: safeData)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }

            task.resume()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func parseJson(usersData: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {


            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(JSONData.self, from: usersData)
            characters = decodedData.results
            print(decodedData.results[0].name)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }







     struct JSONData: Decodable {
         let results: [Results]
     }
     struct Results: Decodable {
         let name: String

     }

    //MARK: - Table view data source
     override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return 1
     }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return characters.count
     }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "user", for: indexPath)

        let guys = characters[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = guys.name


   return cell
     }


}
```

Comment: Hi @Kyrylovep if look for the first line of this URL ( JSON ), you will see this `{"info":{"count":493,"pages":25,"next":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=2","prev":""}`. They already has the next pagination and the previews as well. You need to implement that requests on your code to append more results on your tableview

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde Hi, this is the problem that I don’t know how to implement this in my code, so I ask for help here. Maybe you have an example of how to implement this in code?

Comment: Ok, there is a bunch of code here teaching this, please, look for uitableview with pagination or lazy load, understand the code and then adapt to your code. Is not that simple, but i trust you can do it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to create a Struct matching to your API call response.

[Learn Struct](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/structs-in-swift-for-newbies-bf64f3d40f68)

You can create your struct easily from https://app.quicktype.io/.
Then you can directly convert your response to Character Array..

Next step is show data using array.

set your tableview item count to result array count.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return charcters.count
    }
```

show your character data in cell.don't froget to add character id to cell tag. because you need it when user click on row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! CharcterCell
        let item = characters[indexPath.row]

        cell.lblName.text = item.characterName
        cell.tag = item.chacterId
        return cell
    }
```